# Python 3.5 create .rpm with pyinstaller generated executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, rpm, rpmbuild

I've got a build generated with a pyinstaller.
I need to create .rpm package which will put the executable into the `/usr/bin/` and create a systemd service which will run that executable.

I found this 
https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html and https://docs.python.org/2.0/dist/creating-rpms.html

However it doesn't give me a full picture.

1. Is it possible to make it?
2. What toolset do i need to use? (Basically, `how` to make it).
3. If possible - sample code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, forget about `bdist_rpm`. It's for a `distutils`/`setuptools` project, so you would need a `setup.py` script that invokes `pyinstaller` under the hood to bundle the executable, somehow redefines the `install_scripts` command to be able to package binary executables and also handles the packaging of the `systemd` unit files. Instead, write a spec file which is the instruction manual for `rpm` to build and install your package.

### setup

This is the example project to play with.

```
so-51640995
├── bacon.service
├── bacon.spec
├── bacon.timer
└── spam.py
```

#### `spam.py`

No magic here - prints `eggs` once called. Will be bundled via `pyinstaller` to a binary named `bacon`. I didn't call the project `spam` to avoid ambiguity, because `pyinstaller` also creates a file with `.spec` extension, so that running it does not overwrite the rpm spec file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def eggs():
    print('eggs!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    eggs()
```

#### `bacon.service`

Simple service calling the binary `bacon`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Bacon emitting eggs

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bacon
Restart=always
```

#### `bacon.timer`

Will call `bacon` every ten seconds.

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for bacon to emit eggs from time to time

[Timer]
OnUnitInactiveSec=10s
OnBootSec=10s
Unit=bacon.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

#### `bacon.spec`

The instruction for the package. In `%build` section, we bundle `spam.py`, then install the bundled executable `dist/spam` to `/usr/bin/bacon` along with the `systemd` unit files.

```
Name: bacon
Version: 1
Release: 1
Summary: bacon that shouts 'eggs!' from time to time
License: MIT
Requires: systemd

%description
bacon that shouts 'eggs!' from time to time

%build
pyinstaller --onefile %{_sourcedir}/spam.py

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_bindir}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}
install -m 755 dist/spam %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/bacon
install -m 755 %{_sourcedir}/bacon.service %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}/bacon.service
install -m 755 %{_sourcedir}/bacon.timer %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}/bacon.timer

%files
%{_bindir}/bacon
%{_unitdir}/bacon.service
%{_unitdir}/bacon.timer
```

### build the package

There are lots of tutorials out there that explain building `rpm` packages in-depth, for example [Fedora Packaging Guidelines](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-rpm-packages/index.html), so just listing the minimal sequence of commands here:

```
$ # install the bare minimum of required packages
$ sudo dnf install rpm-build rpm-devel rpmdevtools
$ # first-time setup of build dirs
$ rpmdev-setuptree
$ # copy the source files
$ cp * $HOME/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
$ # invoke the build
$ rpmbuild -ba bacon.spec
```

### test the package

```
$ sudo rpm -ivp $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/bacon-1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

**Edit**: as mentioned in the comments, use `-U` in favor of `-i`. Quote from the `rpm` mans:

> The general form of an rpm upgrade command is
>
> ```
>  rpm {-U|--upgrade} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...
> ```
>
> This upgrades or installs the package currently installed to a newer version. This is the same as install, except all other version(s) of the package are removed after the new package is installed.

So use

```
$ sudo rpm -Uvp $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/bacon-1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

for test installation.

Now `bacon` should be available from command line:

```
$ bacon
eggs!
```

Start the timer:

```
$ sudo systemctl start bacon.timer
$ systemctl status bacon.timer
● bacon.timer - Timer for bacon to emit eggs from time to time
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bacon.timer; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2018-08-07 15:36:28 CEST; 29s ago
  Trigger: Tue 2018-08-07 15:36:58 CEST; 979ms left
```

Check the logs:

```
$ sudo journalctl -u bacon
-- Logs begin at Mon 2017-07-03 12:49:51 CEST, end at Tue 2018-08-07 15:37:02 CEST. --
Aug 07 15:36:28 XXX systemd[1]: Started Bacon emitting eggs.
Aug 07 15:36:28 XXX bacon[128222]: eggs!
Aug 07 15:36:28 XXX systemd[1]: bacon.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 07 15:36:28 XXX systemd[1]: Stopped Bacon emitting eggs.
Aug 07 15:36:28 XXX systemd[1]: Started Bacon emitting eggs.
Aug 07 15:36:28 XXX bacon[128224]: eggs!
Aug 07 15:36:28 XXX systemd[1]: bacon.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 07 15:36:28 XXX systemd[1]: Stopped Bacon emitting eggs.
Aug 07 15:36:28 XXX systemd[1]: Started Bacon emitting eggs.
Aug 07 15:36:29 XXX bacon[128226]: eggs!
...
```

Once verified things work, stop the timer and uninstall `bacon`:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop bacon.timer
$ sudo rpm -e bacon
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl reset-failed
```

Comment: A very minor nitpick: rpm -U, not rpm -i, should always be suggested. The only known usage case for rpm -i is the linux kernel package. Using rpm -I can/will lead to multiply installed packages.

Comment: @hoefling, how can I generate rpm for python3.7.3 itself..? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468483/python-3-7-rpm-creation