# Python 3.7 RPM creation

Tags: python-3.x, rpm

I am trying to create RPM file for Python 3.7.3 by following [Python-RPM](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html)
but getting "file not found" error, please follow below link for the log

[LOG](https://gist.github.com/mnuthan1/c312e5fe41be81fbfac0000e7fd3900f)

Comment: The link is for python packages, not for python itself; if you want to create your own RPM archive for python distribution (why do you want to do that btw?), you'll need to compile CPython from source using a C compiler. Writing an RPM spec for python is anything but trivial; check out existing specs to start with, e.g. the https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/python3/blob/master/f/python3.spec

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will check the link

Comment: @hoefling, that worked with few changes. thank you

Comment: @NuthanKumar can you share your answer? the above link is broken and i cannot find the spec file. i am trying to build python 3.7.9 for amazon linux 1.

Comment: wow, find a python 3.9 spec file. copied it over to my gist https://gist.github.com/pingzh/327d4af9898ac5cfba94209ea8c578a5